# Scala Spark aggregating values from multiple columns into new column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am working on a SQL migration to Cassandra and am having issues with combining multiple columns into a single column. For example, say I have a person who can have one or many races. I currently have 0 or 1 for each individual race. How would I be able to combine that into a single column as a Set?

```
             SQL Schema
+----------------------------------+
- R_White R_Af_American R_Asian    -
-   1          1           1       -
-   0          1           1       -
-   1          0           1       -
-   0          1           0       -
+----------------------------------+

                   Cassandra Temp Desired Schema
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
- R_White R_Af_American R_Asian          Race                       -
-   1          1           1        ["White","Af American", "Asian"]-
-   0          1           1        ["Af American", "Asian"]        -
-   1          0           1        ["White", "Asian"]              -
-   0          1           0        ["Af American"]                 -
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since I am reading in the data from csv, I plan to read in tables to Spark from SQL as they are, perform the combine(into the Race column), then delete all of those columns other than the new Race column.

I have been chaining .withColumn() for other data manipulation on the data but this doesn't seem to fit the when(col("R_White") === 1, somehow_add_to_set).otherwise(...) pattern. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the schema of the table and what do you want add to the set?

Comment: Is this above any more clear? I edited the tables and added a bit more explanation of my scenario

Comment: Tzach has already answered it . didn't that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be to create an array using the `array` function and a `when` expression for each value, and then dropping the `null`s using a UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val dropNulls = udf { (a: Seq[String]) => a.filter(_ != null) }

val result = df.withColumn("Race", dropNulls(array(
  when($"R_White"       === 1, "R_White"),
  when($"R_Af_American" === 1, "R_Af_American"),
  when($"R_Asian"       === 1, "R_Asian")
)))
```

You can also get rid of the hard-coded values by mapping the DataFrame's column names into these `when` expressions:

```
val result = df.withColumn("Race", dropNulls(array(
  df.columns.map(name => when(col(name) === 1, name)): _*
)))

result.show(false)
// +-------+-------------+-------+---------------------------------+
// |R_White|R_Af_American|R_Asian|Race                             |
// +-------+-------------+-------+---------------------------------+
// |1      |1            |1      |[R_White, R_Af_American, R_Asian]|
// |0      |1            |1      |[R_Af_American, R_Asian]         |
// |1      |0            |1      |[R_White, R_Asian]               |
// |0      |1            |0      |[R_Af_American]                  |
// +-------+-------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```